# AntiX linux, iceWM, how to suspend, and require password?

Tags: password, suspend, screen-lock, antix, icewm

In AntiX Linux, using the default iceWM window manager. When I suspend a session, then wake it up, I expect it to ask for my screenlock password.
Current behavior: it just wakes up without asking for password.

Answer (score 1):

"SuspendCommand" string in preferences file can be updated to include "LockCommand" string.

I tried following steps in opensuse running icewm:

- Search for commands used by icewm to lock the screen and suspend the system, "LockCommand" and "SuspendCommand" respectively.

  ```
   $ icewm -p | grep 'LockCommand\|SuspendCommand'
   LockCommand="xscreensaver-command -lock"
   SuspendCommand="test -e /run/systemd/system && systemctl suspend"
  ```
- Append combined command string using "&&" for "SuspendCommand" string in user's preference file in home directory.

  ```
   $ cat >> ~/.icewm/preferences
   SuspendCommand="xscreensaver-command -lock && test -e /run/systemd/system && systemctl suspend"
   CTRL^D
  ```
- Restart icewm eitther using "Logout" -> "Restart Icewm" from "start menu" or using "icewm -r" command.

The updated command will be used when "Sleep Mode" or "Suspend" is clicked from "start menu" -> "Logout".